# How is the mekugi for a katana shaped by traditional methods?

Tags: dowel

A key part of a Japanese sword is the *mekugi*, the tapered peg that fastens the handle to the tang. I am curious what the traditional method is for making this part. I have seen various modern YouTube videos on it, but they are obviously the opinions of westernized hacks that have no relationships to the traditional methods of the Edo Period.

I am looking for an answer that tells how the mekugi was actually made in the pre-machine Japan, not how it could be made using modern tools, which I already know.

Comment: I suppose this is on-topic, though _technically_ (maybe even pedantically...)  this is not about _wood_, as a mekugi is made from specifically chosen smoked bamboo. I mean, bamboo is used in some of the same ways as wood, but it is a different material often with different techniques. That being said, the internet tells us that this is really just a tapered and highly custom fitted peg, though. And a block plane or carving knife (perhaps a drawknife) seem to be the tools most crafstpeople would reach for to make a peg. Did you have a more specific question than that?

Comment: Given the thousands of saya makers spread all over the country at the height of sword production it's entirely possible there wasn't just one method. There may have been multiple traditions as there are with nearly everything of this sort. For the bamboo ones I'm sure they'd have all started with split stock but then some might have whittling theirs freehand using a kiridashi, others pared theirs against a stop with a chisel. Others still might have used a method that can't be guessed at. Regardless, it's a trivially basic shape so why does it matter how it *might* have been made historically?

Comment: @Graphus My experience is that hand methods often have subtle advantages over machine methods, so I want to find out what the method was.

Comment: I don't have any objection to the question (personally, I'd say bamboo is wood-like enough to be considered wood) but you should be aware that there is a pretty low likelihood of getting a quality answer through this forum.  Most questions get 50-100 views total, and unless one of those people also happens to be a fan of historical Japanese swordsmithing you'll probably come up empty.  It will probably be tough in English but I would suggest looking for the equivalent of SAPFM for Japanese swords.

Comment: Not sure about traditional, but this site shows how it is done now. http://www.cottontailcustoms.com/making-mekugi/ I would think the equipment could be replaced in the steps with handtools

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, I'm sure that will fall under the OP's *"westernized hacks that have no relationships to the traditional methods of the Edo Period"* umbrella.

Comment: Probably, which is why I put it as a comment

Answer (score 2):

So, I present this as second-hand opinion only, but a good friend has been studying Samurai martial arts for nearly two decades now. He is, for all intents and purposes, a "Samurai". At least according to a group of people that maintain Samurai as a martial art. So I asked him about this.

Not only has he seen a lot of various swords up close, but has also seen how these various blade types are maintained and crafted. He also owns a traditionally made set of samurai swords. (I won't embarrass myself by presuming I know the names for the blades or set of blades he owns, or understand the significance of the swords as handed down by the Samurai masters he studies with. Suffice to say he has at least one sword that has a *mekugi* installed, and is very familiar with all the parts of a sword that would have a *mekugi* installed.)

According to him, modern crafting of most of the wooden parts of the swords is very similar to what they would have done in the Edo period. That is, not much has *really* changed there. The *mekugi* is still smoked bamboo to reduce compression, and is still chosen for specific fibre orientation.

And, in general, a small assortment of fine carving knives are used to shape the peg for the cleanest fit.

Each peg is custom made and shaped to very high tolerances because the handles are swapped for many ceremonial reasons, and when fitted must allow for a very tight fit without loosening at all.

Of course, we shouldn't forget that, like many similar arts, traditionally one is apprenticed under a master when learning this stuff. Japan still has a rich tradition of apprenticeship to many things, from sake to swords. That is where the technique comes in. Since the question is really "what techniques have successive masters brought to the art since the Edo Period" I admit I don't know. But, according to someone who is familiar with things now, not much has changed because not much has *had* to change. The feeling I get is that such swords were already state-of-the-art well before SE asked this question.

Comment: That is pretty vague. They use carving knives. Okay, I can believe that, but it tells me nothing about the process. Cutting a clean symmetrical taper with hand tools is not easy. There must be some method.

Comment: There is a method: practice. People have been hand shaping spindles and pegs for centuries, and the human hand and eye is surprisingly accurate for this sort of work. Maybe this isn't very exciting, but as far as he knows they just carve pegs out of bamboo. After these many centuries the specific techniques are probably well established, but the takeaway is that the work is done by carving material to an exact fit. Everything else is just experience and practice.

Comment: jdv, his is a perfectly reasonable Answer that I am certain does actually represent the reality of how at least some of these were made historically.... after all, why bother doing it any differently when each one had to be done individually? But don't expect this to be accepted. Dead on the money or just a good Best Answer the OP has a history of not accepting an Answer (and at a guess doesn't upvote any either, but that's just my gut feeling).

Comment: @TreowWyrhta, *"Cutting a clean symmetrical taper with hand tools is not easy."* Actually, it is. This is a trivially basic shape to make as I first described it.... if you've actually tried and practised. I make ferruled tool handles without a lathe and can get a tight sliding fit for the ferrule that requires no epoxy. And mekugi don't have to be symmetrical, many aren't! So I suggest you pare a mekugi, note any issues/difficulties, then make another taking those into account. Rinse and repeat. Once you've done ten or a dozen I guarantee you'll be able to make a mekugi to a high standard.

Comment: @TreowWyrhta I have to echo Graphus here about hand-shaping tapers. Years ago I studied luthiery and I was able to see first hand how masters of that craft could hand-shape a complicated radii using scrapers and similar "knives" to a very high precision using not much more than hand-feel and "squinting down or across the neck". Similarly, seeing chair makers hand shape spindles is a thing of beauty. I just don't have trouble with the notion that a practiced journeyman under the tutelage of a master could not shape a peg for a specific fit and purpose.